# How to create a cross-section ocean profile from netcdf file?

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray, metpy

I would like to create a cross-section of 3D (long, depth, oxygen) along a transect that follows a coastline. E.g. similar to using the MetPy package, however I cannot seem to get the x-y data to work, and I am working with ocean data rather than atmospheric data.

I have tried the following (using the MetPy package as it theoretically does what I need):

```
df="F:/L3_prog_ControlRun201808_ocean_avg.nc" #my dataset
ds=xr.open_dataset(df,engine='netcdf4') 
ds['lon_rho']=ds['lon_rho']-360 #to make the longitude in degrees East

data = ds['oxygen'].metpy.assign_crs({
    "grid_mapping_name": "mercator",
    "latitude_of_projection_origin":43,
    "longitude_of_central_meridian":-66,
    "standard_parallel":0,
    "false_easting":360
}).metpy.assign_y_x()
#this does not create x,y coordinates for some reason

#If the above had worked, I would like to create a cross-section on the transect between:
start=(43.5, -65)
end=(44.5,-63.8)

#using:
cross = cross_section(data, start, end).set_coords(('lat_rho', 'lon_rho'))
print(cross)
```

Comment: hi there! if the above raises errors, can you post the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback)? this includes really important information to help us debug. if not, can you clearly explain why the above does not do what you're hoping to achieve? it would be really helpful if you could show us what your dataset looks like, e.g. by posting the results of `print(ds)` as a formatted code block so we can better understand the structure.

Comment: A full traceback of the error that happens when calling `assign_y_x()` would be helpful. I don't think the `"false_easting":360` is correct unless you're trying to apply an offset of 360 meters to the Mercator-transformed coordinates. It might also be helpful to add the output of `ncdump -h F:/L3_prog_ControlRun201808_ocean_avg.nc` above.